# scripting creation of a linux machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-distro

My need is to store the configuration of a linux machine in a file and be able to replicate the machine (as simply as possible) using the file. The file should be as small as possible.

I think that the following should be possible: create a minimal Linux installation CD which installs the systems from internet and applies some bash script to the resulting system. In principle the ISO of the CD could be very small and could by installed on a real machine (by burning the CD) or on a virtual machine (by means of ISO file).

I wonder if this approach has been implemented... I was not able to figure out the keywords for a google search.

**add:** or even a simpler two-step solution: a minimal linux distribution which has the ability to retrieve packages and software from internet following a configuration script (which could be copied on the system after installation). This would result in even smaller files since the ISO image would be always the same and is not contained in the file describing the system.

Comment: You could customize the `.iso` image. And they all have some post-installation scripts which you could tailor. However, this may be a significant task (weeks or months or years of work).

Comment: In fact I would not be able to do such a thing...

Comment: You should explain much more **why** you want to do that... There are lots of customized Linux distributions already...

Comment: I have several server running some different services. For development and debugging it would be useful to instantiate any of these servers in a virtual machine. To achieve this I would need to store many extremely large image files which, however, contain very little information.

Comment: Assuming all the servers run the same Linux distribution, you could just make a package for all your configured services (e.g. a `.deb` file for Ubuntu or Debian, an `.rpm` file for CentOS, RedHat or Maegia, etc..). And you might also investigate and learn more about [openstack](http://www.openstack.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of linux has been around for long time. a Command Line only (with no GUI) live cd which you would download and boot from it. Usually boot to RAM. these distros come with their own package manager software. these package managers are combination of bash and a programming language mostly Perl.
For example Gentoo; which its livecd is about 100mb i think or maybe less. there are other distros as well